# Align plumb wardrobe and non-plumb window frame

Tags: window-frame, wardrobe

I'm installing a wardrobe at the edge of a window in my 1930s apartment. The sides of the wardrobe are plumb, but the window frame is not, as you can see in the photo -- about 5/8" over roughly 63"H. (The lower piece of blue tape in the picture marks where it's about 1/4" off, and the upper one about 1/2".) There's no easy way to straighten the old metal frame -- opening up the wall isn't feasible -- so it seems my only option is to compensate for it. (I am able to drill/screw into the frame.)

[image]

I thought about covering the entire wardrobe side with 1/4" drywall or plywood, extending back into the frame to make a single surface, but that would leave the extra 1/4" sticking past the door at the front and I can't move the door. Something like thin Masonite would fit at the frame bottom, but I don't know what support I could put behind it with so little depth available (and the frame's vertical lip prevents attaching anything behind the wardrobe). So, I'm at a loss, and would really appreciate any ideas. Thanks so much!!

Comment: Pictures of the back of the wardrobe would help. Possible to cut/shape/carve the back to match the wall/window frame or to add on a piece(1x2) to match. It will depend on what tools you have.

Comment: You've described the situation well, but haven't explicitly said what you consider to be the problem that needs to be solved. (Is it creating aesthetic problems? Is it interfering with the operation of the door or the air conditioner? etc.?)

Comment: Is this an OCD issue?

Comment: @RayButterworth, it's aesthetic. I'd like the wardrobe to have more of a built-in look, with the side of the wardrobe blending into the window frame -- visually at a minimum (i.e, they just line up nicely), or ideally as a single surface with no visible gap.

Comment: @crip659, the problem is that anything I added would be misaligned either to the wardobe or the window frame -- I'm trying to have them match.

Comment: You want the front to be plumb, but the back to match the wall/window.  If you cut/carve the back or add a piece of similar material to the back edge(so the side is flat) that is cut/carved to match the differences between the wall and wardrobe.  So a 5/8 piece that goes from 5/8 to 0 inches.  If the wardrobe is 12 inches now, you make it 12 and 5/8 inches at the top to 12 inches at the bottom, or whatever is needed, or remove 5/8 at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shim the bottom (right side) of the furniture until it lines up with the window.

If the windowframe isn't plumb, the furniture next to it should not be either...

Basically, in an old house (or sometimes not so old) your options are to jack the house so some part of it is level or plumb (getting all parts that way may not be achievable, and jacking houses comes with risks of its own) or accept that to look like it belongs, the new thing will need to match the old, hard to move thing, with whatever compromises that entails. Few things on shelves care much if the shelf is perfectly level. Most that do can be leveled on an un-level shelf.

Comment: Only if it's very poorly built, as the whole thing should rotate as a unit (pivoting on the left base) when shimmed on the bottom right. I suppose you could wedge-shim the whole base if it's that poorly constructed. The right door self closing might well be an expected result, though.

Comment: Was there a comment that got deleted? It looks like you're responding to one. Anyway, shimming might work, especially since it's in a corner and the other wall is similarly off vertical. The downside is that the shelves would then be off-level, so I need to think about whether that will matter.

Comment: Yes, there was such a comment. Claimed the doors would not line up.

Comment: I moved the wardrobe over slightly and shimmed it, and it's lining up perfectly (or as close to perfectly as you can get in an old building). The slope of the shelves will be negligible, and as you say most things won't care much. Next step will be to fill in the gap between the window frame and wardrobe, but that's a new question. Thanks!